# Not able to Deploy Django + Python 3 + PostgreSQL to EC2

Tags: python, django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a ready django project perfectly running on localserver. Now I need to deploy same on AWS EC2. As I am self learned developer and new to it, I went through tons of tutorials but could not find any easy explained tutorials on how to deploy django project using python 3 and postgres to EC2. Please guide me if anybody is interested to else provide me with tutorials explaining the same.

Answer (score 1):

For the ease of deployment consider using [Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/documentation/elastic-beanstalk/), it uses same EC2 instances, but already configured for easy deployments.

> With AWS Elastic Beanstalk, you can quickly deploy and manage applications in the AWS cloud without worrying about the infrastructure that runs those applications. AWS Elastic Beanstalk reduces management complexity without restricting choice or control. You simply upload your application, and AWS Elastic Beanstalk automatically handles the details of capacity provisioning, load balancing, scaling, and application health monitoring.

Here is [tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html) how to deploy django application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: Is it free for the first year or do we need to pay for the resources like ec2?

Comment: @RachitAgarwal as docs says **"There is no additional charge for Elastic Beanstalk. You pay only for the underlying AWS resources that your application consumes. For details about pricing, see the Elastic Beanstalk service detail page."**.

Comment: can you hekp me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39703086/how-can-i-create-ebextensions-01-packages-config-file ?

Answer (score 0):

Best tutorial for deploying Django application on AWS EC2 [here.](http://agiliq.com/blog/2013/08/minimal-nginx-and-gunicorn-configuration-for-djang/)

If you are a newbie in Django production then first you need to know what is the **Nginx** and **Gunicorn** and what's the difference between them from [here.](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-differences-between-nginx-and-gunicorn)

then read the tutorial for how to deploy Django application on AWS EC2  .

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13774738)

Comment: @AlexanderFarber I will edit the answer soon and thanks for a suggestion .