# How can I create .ebextensions/01_packages.config file?

Tags: django, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am deploying my django app on Elastic Beanstalk and going through the tutorial step by step. The is step involved "Customizing the Deployment Process" to add additional packages to Ec2. I need to add the following packages:

```
packages:
  yum:
    git: []
    postgresql93-devel: []
```

and asked to create .ebextensions/01_packages.config at the root of the project and I am not abel to create it. Anyone please help me with that. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you not able to create it? It's just a folder and file.

Comment: is it a simple .txt file I need to create with an extension of .config?

Comment: Just create file with _.config_ extension. You also can create .txt file and then while renaming change its extension.

Answer (score 0):

Following may help you:

You need to follow following hierarchy :

```
ProjectFolder
    settings.py
    urls.py
App1
    models.py
    views.py
.ebextensions
    01_packages.config
.elasticbeanstalk
    config.yml
.git
manage.py
requirements.txt
.gitignore
```

And following code in 01_packages.config :

```
packages:
..yum:
....git: []
....postgresql93-devel: []
```

.(dot) you can refer it as number of spaces.

Comment: First of all, as you call `ProjectFolder` could be divided and settings files could be split into different files for every environment. Secondly, There should be _requerements.txt_ file, there is none in your structure.

Comment: I have just shown required structure for him or else we need lot to work with elasticbean stack but I think we have details procedure given by AWS.

Comment: It's just not completely clear why you would show that, because all it needs: _manage.py_, _requirements.txt_, .ebextension folder, and project files|folders. That's all.

Comment: I am not pushing you, don't think so, but for not qualified  developer your structure snipped could be not so obvious and etc. Cheers, mate!

Comment: @vishes_shell I need to show it because I am need to install postgresql93-devel: []

Comment: @RachitAgarwal sorry, i didn't get you